# PHP Parse.com - How to include pointers within array using curl_setopt?

Tags: php, curl, parse-platform

First, I want to say that I am completely new to the parses [PHP API](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest) and PHP curl_setopt.

What I want to do is retrieve each object being pointed to in my array `posts`:

(`posts` is an array of pointers column in my `Post` Class, stored on parse)

```
public 'posts' => 
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[7]
      public '__type' => string 'Pointer' (length=7)
      public 'className' => string 'Post' (length=4)
      public 'objectId' => string 'uXXXXXXXXq' (length=10)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[8]
      public '__type' => string 'Pointer' (length=7)
      public 'className' => string 'Post' (length=4)
      public 'objectId' => string 'CXXXXXXXXr' (length=10)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[9]
      public '__type' => string 'Pointer' (length=7)
      public 'className' => string 'Post' (length=4)
      public 'objectId' => string 'xXXXXXXXXe' (length=10)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[10]
      public '__type' => string 'Pointer' (length=7)
      public 'className' => string 'Post' (length=4)
      public 'objectId' => string '5XXXXXXXXI' (length=10)
```

For retrieving data I am doing something like this:

```
    $post_tbl_name = "Post";        
    $post_url = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/$post_tbl_name/$pid" ;

    $headers = parse_get_header();

    $handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url );
    curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    //curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");    
    // Something like this ???? Idk this gives me null
    curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
        "include" => "posts"
    ));     

    $response = curl_exec( $handle );

    if (!$response) {
        die('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));
    }

    curl_close( $handle );
```

I did not include my `parse_get_header()` function but it is correct and I am able to pull data from parse. It's just including these pointers in my query that gives me trouble.

Any insight on how this can be done?